# Reactions to messages Telegram/Telethon

Tags: telethon

The "telethon" library has a "get messages" method, with which you can get a message and information about it, including comments.

But can you get reactions?
https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getMessageReactionsList

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do this via telethon.
However, you can get a list of reactions to messages using **pyrogram**: [GetMessageReactionsList](https://docs.pyrogram.org/telegram/functions/messages/get-message-reactions-list?highlight=reactions#pyrogram.raw.functions.messages.GetMessageReactionsList)

Something like that:

```
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram.raw.functions.messages import GetMessageReactionsList


app = Client(
    "my_account",
    api_id=12345678,
    api_hash='XXX'
)

chat_id = -123456789

with app:
    peer = app.resolve_peer(chat_id)

    for message in app.iter_history(chat_id=chat_id):
        reactions = app.send(
            GetMessageReactionsList(
                peer=peer,
                id=message.message_id,
                limit=100
            )
        )
```

**UPD**
Found an easier way:

```
with app:
    peer = app.resolve_peer(chat_id)

    for message in app.iter_history(chat_id=chat_id):
        print(message.reactions)
```

Answer (score 2):

In `telethon 1.25.4` you can get it easily:

```
with TelegramClient(session, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    for message in client.get_messages('@'+channelusername):
        print(message.reactions)
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently was looking for reactions as well and discovered the `GetMessagesReactionsRequest()` function from the Telegram API methods list:

```
with TelegramClient(session, api_id, api_hash) as client:
     reaction = client(GetMessagesReactionsRequest(chat_test, id=[4775]))
```

Where ID is the message ID. There might be a more efficient solution, as soon as I found it I'll let you know.